# Brunch config file: what is the difference between exports.config and module.exports = config?

Tags: brunch

In the guide of the Brunch website, they start the config file as following `module.exports = config:`, however most of the skeletons you can find on the same website use another syntax `exports.config =`.

What is the difference between them? Are both javascript CommonJS Module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look directly at the doc: [module node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules). Something I should have done at first :)

> The exports variable that is available within a module starts as a reference to module.exports. As with any variable, if you assign a new value to it, it is no longer bound to the previous value.
>
> If you want the root of your module's export to be a function (such as a constructor) or if you want to export a complete object in one assignment instead of building it one property at a time, assign it to module.exports instead of exports.

Finally, they said:

> As a guideline, if the relationship between exports and module.exports seems like magic to you, ignore exports and only use module.exports.

Et voilà!